# Как выровнять интерлиньяж между блоками?

Tags: html, css, отступы

Есть 2 блока в футере: в первом - список меню, а во втором - сплошной текст адреса. Как сделать так, чтобы интерлиньяж текста стал равный меню (не наоборот)
Варианты с приблизительными `line-height` не предлагать, я и сам знаю как. Меня устроит решение только с равными интерлиньяжными отступами. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/dgnLor2o/)

```css
.footer-widgets.col-4 .block {
    width: 43.4782608696%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4.347826087%;
}
.widget_nav_menu ul li {
    margin-bottom: .6180469716em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-widgets col-4 fix">
  <div class="block footer-widget-3">
    <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><span class="gamma widget-title">Информация</span>
      <div class="menu-futer-3-container">
        <ul id="menu-futer-3" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-308" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-308"><a href="http://#">Гарантия и сервис</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-309" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-309"><a href="http://#">Карта сайта</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-310" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-310"><a href="http://#">Корзина</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block footer-widget-4">
    <div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text"><span class="gamma widget-title">Контакты</span>
      <div class="textwidget">
        <p>Какой-то адрес тра-м-па-пам, Республика Папуа Новая Гвинея, индекс 3436432, планета земля</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если убрать все `margin` с пунктов, то все задается четко с помощью `line-height`, не надо ничего приблизительно подбирать.

```
.widget_nav_menu ul li {
    margin:0; /*Здесь убрал отступ*/
}
.widget_nav_menu ul li, .footer-widget-4 p{
    line-height: 30px; /*поставил сколько надо в px, чтобы не влияла высота шрифтов*/
}
```

Что касается мистического интерлиньяжа, такого в CSS в строчных элементах (не блоковых) нет.

**Рабочий пример на вашей основе:**

```css
.footer-widgets.col-4 .block {
    width: 43.4782608696%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4.347826087%;
}
.widget_nav_menu ul li {
    margin:0;
}
.widget_nav_menu ul li, .footer-widget-4 p{
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-widgets col-4 fix">
  <div class="block footer-widget-3">
    <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><span class="gamma widget-title">Информация</span>
      <div class="menu-futer-3-container">
        <ul id="menu-futer-3" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-308" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-308"><a href="http://#">Гарантия и сервис</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-309" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-309"><a href="http://#">Карта сайта</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-310" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-310"><a href="http://#">Корзина</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block footer-widget-4">
    <div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text"><span class="gamma widget-title">Контакты</span>
      <div class="textwidget">
        <p>Какой-то адрес тра-м-па-пам, Республика Папуа Новая Гвинея, индекс 3436432, планета земля</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```